# Is it possible for a sha512 hash to start with 64 zeros?

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, sha512

I was just thinking about numbers repeating in hashes and I was wondering if it was possible for half of a sha512 hash to consist of 64 consecutive zeros.

Comment: Probably -- if it couldn't, that would at least theoretically be a weakness. At the same time, good luck finding an input that produces that particular output.

Comment: Haha, I know, it would take a lot of computing power I am sure.

Comment: That's putting it mildly. In fact, using every computer on earth, chances of finding it before we all die are minuscule.

Comment: By 64 consecutive zeros you mean zero hexdigits? i.e. "only" 32 zero bytes? Or do you mean zero bits?

Comment: @CodesInChaos what would be the difference?

Comment: @Max00355 Why 64, and in what base? Do you just mean to ask if it would be 0? Note that sha512 is 64 bytes, i.e. 512 bits.

Answer (score 2):

As Chris said - you should have the same chance of getting such hash as any other hash. So the  probability of that is 1 / 2^64.

If you would like to find such a hash you can hope someone already found it and put it in [**rainbow tables**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table). I tried to find such a hash [here](http://crackstation.net/), but failed :)

Also you could tried it for your own. I tried with such a naive script:

```
import random
import string
import hashlib
import datetime
s=string.lowercase+string.digits
random.seed(datetime.datetime.utcnow())

while 1:
    x = ''.join([random.choice(s) for a in range(random.randint(2,1024))])
    if hashlib.sha512(x).hexdigest().startswith('0000000000000000'):
        print x
        exit()
```

But then it occurred to me that I still have low chances. So.. the expected number of iterations algoritm has to do is 2^64. My machine made 100000 iterations in

```
real    1m7.762s
user    1m5.908s
sys     0m0.123s
```

So it's 0.0006776 seconds for iterations.

To sum up - it would take about 396357000 *years* to get the result on my machine without optimizing.

Well, good luck!

Comment: Note for the record that sha512 is 64 bytes which is 512 bits, so there are 2**512 possible values of sha512.

Answer (score 1):

It's equally as likely as any other hash value, or should be.

Comment: Very interesting, I wonder what string would equal that hash.